# Keras LSTM input dimension setting

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I was trying to train a LSTM model using keras but I think I got something wrong here.

I got an error of

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_17_input to have
>   3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 0, 20)

while my code looks like

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, activation="relu", dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, input_shape=(None, 20, 64)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      epochs=10)
```

where `X_train` has a shape of `(10000, 20)` and the first few data points are like

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0, ..., 40, 40,  9],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 33, 20, 51],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 54, 54, 50],
...
```

and `y_train` has a shape of `(10000, )`, which is a binary (0/1) label array.

Could someone point out where I was wrong here?

Comment: you say `input_shape=(None, 20, 64)` but your input has only two dimensions `(10000, 20)` ?

Comment: @AndreHolzner I once tried to set input_shape = (10000, 20), but no luck. The error is ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_28_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10000, 20)

Comment: try setting `input_shape=(None, 20, 1)` and resize the input to size `(10000,20,1)`. E.g. if your input is in a numpy array use [numpy.resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html).

Comment: @AndreHolzner Just tried. Got a training np.array with a size (10000, 20, 1). However, there is still an error saying the dimension is not matched. I then changed the input size to (20, 1) and it works now!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here's what's happened.

First up, `LSTM`, like all layers in Keras, accepts two arguments: `input_shape` and `batch_input_shape`. The difference is in convention that `input_shape` **does not contain the batch size**, while `batch_input_shape` is the **full input shape including the batch size**.

Hence, the specification `input_shape=(None, 20, 64)` tells keras to expect a 4-dimensional input, which is not what you want. The correct would have been just `(20,)`.

But that's not all. LSTM layer is a recurrent layer, hence it expects a 3-dimensional input `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. That's why the correct specification is `input_shape=(20, 1)` or `batch_input_shape=(10000, 20, 1)`. Plus, your training array should also be reshaped to denote that it has `20` time steps and `1` input feature per each step.

Hence, the solution:

```py
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, 2)  # makes it (10000,20,1)
...
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(..., input_shape=(20, 1)))
```

Comment: dear sir, I send you a lot of love.