# Python - LSTM based RNN required 3D input?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

i am trying to build a deep learning network based on LSTM RNN here is what is tried

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
import numpy as np

train = np.loadtxt("TrainDatasetFinal.txt", delimiter=",")
test = np.loadtxt("testDatasetFinal.txt", delimiter=",")

y_train = train[:,7]
y_test = test[:,7]

train_spec = train[:,6]
test_spec = test[:,6]


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(1415684, 8),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, input_dim=8, input_length=1415684, return_sequences=True))
##model.add(Embedding(1, 256, input_length=5000))
##model.add(LSTM(64,input_dim=1, input_length=10, activation='sigmoid',
##               return_sequences=True, inner_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(train_spec, y_train, batch_size=2000, nb_epoch=11)
score = model.evaluate(test_spec, y_test, batch_size=2000)
```

but it gets me the following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1415684, 1)
```

Here is a sample from the dataset

(Patient Number, time in millisecond, accelerometer x-axis,y-axis, z-axis,magnitude, spectrogram,label (0 or 1))

```
1,15,70,39,-970,947321,596768455815000,0
1,31,70,39,-970,947321,612882670787000,0
1,46,60,49,-960,927601,602179976392000,0
1,62,60,49,-960,927601,808020878060000,0
1,78,50,39,-960,925621,726154800929000,0
```

in the dataset i am using the only the spectrogram as input feature and the label (0 or 1) as the output the total traing samples is 1,415,684

Answer (score 9):

Your main mistake is misunderstanding how LSTM (or any RNN, actually) works and what it accepts as an input. A single training example for LSTM network consists of a *sequence* and a label. For example, this...

```
1,15,70,39,-970,947321,596768455815000,0
1,31,70,39,-970,947321,612882670787000,0
1,46,60,49,-960,927601,602179976392000,0
1,62,60,49,-960,927601,808020878060000,0
1,78,50,39,-960,925621,726154800929000,0
```

... is a sequence of length 5, with 8 features. The label for the whole sequence is the label column at the next row. Note that this is just *one example*; a batch means several such sequences and labels.

---

Now, concerning Keras, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48141688/712995):

> LSTM layer is a recurrent layer, hence it expects a 3-dimensional input `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`.

Let's look closely at your specification: `input_shape=(1415684, 8)` tells keras to expect sequences of length `1415684`, in which each item has `8` features. And all this not accounting for the batch size, which is `2000`.

This clearly won't work, because `1415684` is way too long LSTM sequence. Empirical evidence shows that LSTM can learn up to 100 time steps, so feeding larger sequences won't make it learn better. Not to mention that it's not memory and time efficient.

What you should do instead is choose a smaller `timesteps` parameter, say `timesteps=64`, and split your data into chunks of `timesteps` subsequent rows. Chunks may intersect. The batch of those means `batch_size * timesteps` rows in total, each with `8` columns. The `y_train` should contain the ground truth for each training sequence. Keras won't do this preparation step, so you'll have to do it manually.