# When to choose batch_input_shape vs input_shape (Keras LSTM)? Pro/con

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

Well, it might be a simple question, but I'm just wondering when I should choose `batch_input_shape` over `input_shape` in Keras LSTM layers. I always use `input_shape` and define the batch size at runtime, since most tutorials I've seen so far recommend this method. But then what would be a reason to define the batch size at compile time using `batch_input_size`? Which method is preferable and why?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: But one more question: Am I right that when using input_shape, batch_size is not fixed and the network can be fed with different batch sizes during runtime and when using batch_input_shape, batch_size is fixed?

Comment: This depends on the parameter `stateful` of your `LSTM`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between input\_shape and batch\_input\_shape in LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374508/whats-the-difference-between-input-shape-and-batch-input-shape-in-lstm)

Comment: thank you @alift, but thats the same answer as AloneTogether's