# Keras Convolution1D input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a simple Convolutional NN with:

- 340 samples,
- 260 rows per sample
- 16 features per row.

I thought the order of the shape is (batch_size, steps, input_dim), which would mean (340, 16, 260) *I believe*.

Current code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(340, 16, 260)))
# model.add(Conv2D(64, 2, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
# model.add(Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, batch_size=16, epochs=1000)
```

I am getting an error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

I am very lost and believe that my shapes are off. Could someone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48141688/8397234), layers in Keras, accept two arguments: `input_shape` and `batch_input_shape`. The difference is that `input_shape` **does not** contain the batch size, while `batch_input_shape` is the **full input shape**, including the batch size.

Based on this, I think the specification `input_shape=(340, 16, 260)` tells keras to expect a 4-dimensional input, which is not what you want. The correct argument would be `batch_input_shape=(340, 16, 260)`.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, the error is now :

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (16, 260) but got array with shape (260, 16)

Comment: Was this when using `batch_input_shape=(340, 16, 260)`?